# Indexed character tables for wreath products in Sage and GAP

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, characters, gap, sage

I am trying to obtain character table for the Hyperoctahedral group $\mathcal{H}_n$ in Sage using GAP.
This group arises as the wreath product $\mathcal{C}_2 \wr \mathcal{S}_n$, so of course I can write (calling gap from sage)

```
n=4
group = gap.WreathProduct(gap.SymmetricGroup(2), gap.SymmetricGroup(n))
character_table_1 = gap.CharacterTable(group)
```

However, knowing that conjugacy classes and irreps of $\mathcal{H}_n$ are indexed by pairs of partitions (of $k$ and of $n-k$), I would like to see this in the output. Specifically, I would like to be able to write something like

```
 Irr(character_table)[ [[1],[2,1]] ] # (1)
```

To obtain the character corresponding to the given pair of partitions. Fortunately, this is possible:

```
n=4
cyclic_group_character_table = gap.CharacterTable(gap.SymmetricGroup(2))
character_table_2 = gap.CharacterTableWreathSymmetric(cyclic_group_character_table, n)
```

However, unlike the first character table, this one doesn't store the underlying group, so when I get the character using `(1)`, I can't apply it to elements of `group` (and also, another package I am using expects to have the group stored in the character table).

Now, it seems like the exact thing I need is implemented in GAP, namely the function `CharacterTableWithStoredGroup`, which (I think) should give me the old character table but with the underlying group stored within it. I tried it out:

```
group = gap.WreathProduct(gap.SymmetricGroup(2), gap.SymmetricGroup(n))
character_table_3 = gap.CharacterTableWithStoredGroup(group, character_table_2)
```

But the function returns `fail`. If I understand it correctly, according to the documentation this should work.

My question is why does the code fail? and is there some other way to get the object I'm after?

Comment: Have you tried running the corresponding commands directly in GAP (invoked as "sage -gap" from the command line)? That would show whether the problem is with GAP itself or with the Sage interface to it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! 
Just tried it. Doesn't work unfortunately, still returning `fail' which apparently indicates "GAP cannot identify the classes of G up to automorphisms of tbl"